# Typecasting std: :vector<double> to Eigen: :VectorXd?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, casting, eigen3

I have looked hard online for an answer; however, none of the provided ones fix my issue.

I have tried this so far

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
/*More code goes here*/
...
std::vector<double> _0to99;
/*putting values into the vector*/
Eigen::VectorXi X = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(_0to99.data(), _0to99.size());
```

However, Visual Studio tells me this error:

no instance of constructor "Eigen::Map::Map [with PlainObjectType=Eigen::Matrix, MapOptions=0, StrideType=Eigen::Stride<0, 0>]" matches the argument list

and

'< function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Eigen::Map>'

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated! Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Your attempt actually tries to initialize using a `double*` and an integer, so `std::vector` is not involved directly.  So is there a way to construct an `Eigen::Map` using an array or pointer to a buffer?

Comment: VectorXi does not contain double. Did you mean VectorXd?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am confused about the reason why that is happening. What would be a way to fix this?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Maybe? My point was to create a dynamic vector, and the documentation said that was the way to do so. Is VectorXd still dynamic?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I tried doing "Eigen::VectorXd X(_0to99.data());" and I got the following error: YOU_CALLED_A_FIXED_SIZE_METHOD_ON_A_DYNAMIC_SIZE_MATRIX_OR_VECTOR

Comment: @TomOconnor -- Forget about `sd::vector` for the moment.  What if you had a plain old `double myData[100]` and filled it with values.  How would you get that to populate `Eigen::Map`?  Is that possible?  If not, then using `vector::data()` isn't going to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry for the dumb follow up question, but I guess I am sort of stuck after following your advice. I declared "double _0to99[100];" and then I wrote the following statement "Eigen::VectorXi X = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi>(_0to99, 100);". However, I still got the errors mentioned in my question on top. Could you please guide me a little bit further?

Comment: Yes, you get the same error because you're doing the same thing with vector.  So basically you should be investigating how to populate `Eigen::Map` using a plain array first.  Once you find the right function(s) to do that, then you can use the `std::vector::data()` method.  I would be surprised if there was not a way to use a plain array, and instead you have to "package" your data into some special type first just to initialize (again, I have never used `Eigen`).

Comment: 'I tried doing "Eigen::VectorXd X(_0to99.data());"' Why are you changing everything at once? Just replacing VectorXi with VectorXd lets your original code compile! The error you get is pretty clear, the size is dynamic so you have to pass it as argument. Please do visit Eigen's documentation is you need to ask if VectorXd is dynamic.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Apparently doing either "Eigen::VectorXd X = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(_0to99.data(), 100);" or   "Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> v(_0to99.data(), 100);" works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: ^
@PaulMcKenzie ^ Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @TomOconnor -- If that works, then now you can use `std::vector` in the call (so that it looks like your original attempt):  `Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> v(your_vector.data(), your_vector.size());`.  Remeber that `std::vector` is just a wrapper around a dynamic array, and to get to the array, the `vector::data()` is used.